# How to validate mutiple fileds in django forms and an additional custom clean function?

Tags: python, django

To validate the single fields is no problem. self.cleaned_data shows the values!

But when i want to print self.cleaned_data in the **clean method** the result is None for all values! How is that going to happen? I also tried to get the data with Super() ...but no luck...
Any ideas?

```
def validator_number_or_one_letter(fieldvalue):
    if not re.match("^[A-Za-z0-9]*$", fieldvalue) or len(fieldvalue)>1:

        raise forms.ValidationError("Error, Error!")


class CodeForm(forms.Form):

    letter_one = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': '#','requiried':'required','required': 'true','size':'1','class':'first-field' }))
    letter_two =forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': '#','requiried':'required','required': 'true','size':'1' }))
    letter_three = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': '#', 'requiried':'required','required': 'true','size':'1' }))
    letter_four = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': '#','requiried':'required','required': 'true','size':'1' }))
    letter_five = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': '#','requiried':'required','required': 'true','size':'1' }))

    def clean(self):
        #cleaned_data = super(CodeForm, self).clean()  ###this does not work either
        #print cleaned_data ###this does not work either
        print self.cleaned_data['letter_one']

    def clean_letter_one(self):
        validator_number_or_one_letter(self.cleaned_data['letter_one'])

    def clean_letter_two(self):
        validator_number_or_one_letter(self.cleaned_data['letter_two'])

    def clean_letter_three(self):
        validator_number_or_one_letter(self.cleaned_data['letter_three'])

    def clean_letter_four(self):
        validator_number_or_one_letter(self.cleaned_data['letter_four'])

    def clean_letter_five(self):
        validator_number_or_one_letter(self.cleaned_data['letter_five'])
```

Comment: What happens if you check the uncleaned `self.data['letter_one']`?

Comment: please return value in your every method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it is the only problem, but your clean_() methods must return the cleaned value.